# Confused in triple Integral bounds

Tags: integration

I'm asked to find the volume between the sphere with radius of $3$ and $y = 1$ in cartesian coordinates.
The image is like this :
[image: The Graph]

I tried to solve it by two ways but I get different answers.
What is my mistake?
here are solutions :

$$\int_1^3\int_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-x^2-y^2}}1\ \text{d}z\ \text{d}x\ \text{d}y=\frac{28\pi}{3}\approx29.3215$$

$$\int_{-3}^{3}\int_{-\sqrt{9-z^2}}^{\sqrt{9-z^2}}\int_1^{\sqrt{9-x^2-z^2}}1\ \text{d}y\ \text{d}x\ \text{d}z=9\pi\approx28.2743$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint. Find the volume of the [Spherical Cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap) with $r=3$,  $h=r-1=2$ and $a=\sqrt{r^2-1^2}=\sqrt{8}$. Hence
$$V=\frac{\pi h}{6}\left(3a^2+h^2\right)=\frac{28\pi}{3}.$$

Comment: so the first solution is correct,what is the problem with the second one ?

Comment: Yes. In the second one it is not true that $z\in [-3,3]$.

Comment: Oh! what a mistake! thank you !